# Is there any statistical difference between 10 Bernoulli trials and 1 binomial trial with parameter n = 10?

Tags: binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

By "statistical difference" I mean literally any difference between the two of statistical import, beyond of course the notation or words used.

Comment: A binomial distribution occurs when you do 10 Bernoulli trials but you don't call it a binomial trial.

Comment: They are one and the same.

Comment: @Zahava you might find my answer enlightening...

Comment: @Glen_b You are right of course, but from a pure probabilistic point of view (not for statistical inference) you can easily calculate one out of the other so they are "equivalent" in this sense.

Comment: @Zahava If they're equivalent in the sense that you can calculate one from the other, my binomial observation is "6". How many '1's did I have in the first four trials? If you don't know, plainly they're not equivalent at all. The binomial is a *summary* of the information, reducing 10 values to 1 and throwing away the other 9-dimensions. That may be a sensible thing to do in many cases -- if the model is correct, for example, the other information doesn't tell us anything (there's no point in knowing how many 1's in the first 4 trials); but if the model is wrong, the other 9 dimensions matter

Answer (score 9):

Yes they're different in a simple, fairly obvious sense.

Ten Bernoulli trials (presumed to be independent with with common parameter $p$) is *ten* 0/1 values, so an observation on it looks like "$(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0)$".

The *sum* of such a vector is distributed as $\text{binomial}(10,p)$; an observation on that looks like "$4$".

With an observation from the first thing (ten Bernoulli trials) I can answer a question like "was there a 1 on the third trial?" or "what's the difference in the number of 1's in the first 5 trials and the second 5 trials?". With the second thing (one observation on a binomial), I simply cannot consider those questions, since I have compressed the information from ten values to a single number. The first thing contains more information (in a particular sense) $-$ but if the assumptions are true it's not got any more information about $p$; the sum is sufficient for that.

For example, if you want to answer a question "is my binomial model reasonable?" you might want to consider the possibility that $p$ might change over the course of the trials, or that the trials may be serially correlated. You *can't* begin to assess that from one binomial value (you've thrown out the information that would let you discern if the binomial model was suitable) but you can consider such a question from a set of $n$ Bernoulli trials.

Therefore there's a clear "difference of statistical import" here.

[Ten trials is small enough that you can't get much power in relation to those questions, but with a binomial *you simply can't address it at all*. If I had say a hundred trials, though, or a thousand, I could do some more interesting things to address those questions, and might hope to identify the extent to which my model was not really describing the situation.]

Comment: The curly braces might be taken to imply an unordered (multi-)set. </pedantry>

Comment: @GeoMatt22 They might but then it would be odd to present the jumbled 0's and 1s, rather than as say $\{0^6,1^4\}$. I have converted braces to parentheses in the hope of more clearly conveying the intent.

Comment: @Glen_b I understand what you are saying, but let's just say I add all the results of Bernoulli trials and get a number. Can I say that it is binomial(10, p) ;

Comment: If the trials are i.i.d., yes. This is a common assumption, but you need to consider for each set of cirmustances whether those assumptions make sense